# .NET ApplicationSettingsBase Should I call Upgrade() every time I load?

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade, application-settings, applicationsettingsbase

We have application settings derived from `ApplicationSettingsBase`. When we push a new version of our app we need to call:

```
  //
  // Summary:
  //     Updates application settings to reflect a more recent installation of the
  //     application.
  public virtual void Upgrade();
```

(from the meta-data)

Now there are some tricky ways to determine if your settings need to be upgraded such as [this post](http://web.archive.org/web/20120618125432/http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2005/12/09/246.aspx) which would seem to me to only ever upgrade your settings once. Now I could store the current version of my application in the settings and compare whenever I instantiate the settings, if it is different to the current version then I could upgrade.

My question is why not just call `Upgrade()` every time I instantiate the settings? That way i know I will never be out of date.

Comment: the link no longer works

Comment: I found a cached copy from the web archive, so changed the link to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method described in the linked post does work. I've used that method myself. When your application version changes the settings will be reset to their defaults and the `UpdateRequired` property will be `true`.

So no, you don't have to call `Upgrade` every time your app starts.

Comment: of course! when a new version gets installed a new version of the settings gets created. I was thinking that the old version would get instantiated and then upgraded to the new settings when in fact the new settings will import the old ones.